# How to handle missing values while calculating average in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a dataset with many missing values as double slash (//). Part of the data is

```
input.txt
30
//
10
40
23
44
//
//
31
//
54
// and so on
```

I would like calculate the average in each 6 rows interval without considering the missing values. I was trying with this, but not getting what I need.

```
awk '{if ($1 -ne "//") sum += $1} (NR%6)==0 {print(sum/NR)}' input.txt
```

It is giving

```
24.5
19.33
```

But the answer should come

```
29.4
42.5
```

Comment: I don't think you can get those answers even if you do it manually. What do you mean by *average*? If you are finding average in 6 rows, shouldn't it be `sum/6`

Comment: What I want is it should not consider the missing values. It should calculate the average of integers in 6 rows. i.e in my example result should give (30+10+40+23+44)/5 and (31+54)/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `awk` a bit to obtain the output as

```
$ awk '!/\//{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print sum/count;sum=count=0}'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '!/\//{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print sum/count;sum=count=0}' file
29.4
42.5
```

**What it does?**

- `!/\//{sum += $1; count++}`

  - `!/\//` pattern checks if the line doesn't contain `/`
  - `{sum += $1; count++}` when the line doesn't contain `/` this action is performed, which sums the column 1, `$1` to `sum` and increments a `count` which essentially tells us how many digits `awk` has seen till the next print.
- `NR%6==0{print sum/count;sum=count=0}` When the number of records, `NR` is multiple of `6`, we print the average, `sum/count` and resets the `count` and `sum` variables.

**Edit**

To print the last set of lines which may be less than `6` in number, we can use an `END` block as

```
$ awk '!/\//{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print sum/count;sum=count=0} END{print sum/count}' file
29.4
42.5
```

- `END{print sum/count}'` The `END` block will be updated when the file reaches its end.

**Edit 2**

Edge case when no numbers occur in the 6 lines, the above script can lead to divide by zero error. The print statement can be formatted to handle this case.

```
print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}
```

- This is a basic ternary operator which checks if count is non zero, if so prints the divided value , else print `count`, 0

**Test**

```
$ awk '!/\//{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}' file
29.4
42.5
0
```

Comment: The resetting of the counter and sum is the most change; the rest is semi-cosmetic.  Do you need an END block to print the average of the last N lines (where N < 6)?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you please suggest how can I do it if there is no integer in a particular 6 rows. This command is not working there.

Comment: @Kayan That would be easy. Add and `END` block. will update my answer.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R. Thank you, but still some wrong is going on when there is no integer in all 6 rows. e.g. input.txt
30
//
10
40
23
44
//
//
31
//
54
//
//
//
//
//
//
//

Comment: @Kayan I think you are getting a divide by zero. It can be handled by the  edit 2 in the answer.